# ¿Por qué sincronizar hilos?

Tags: java

Reinicio el siguiente programa varias veces. Tengo que estudiar el valor final de n en un contexto multihilo, ofrecer una explicación y resolver el problema con la instrucción `synchronized`.

```
class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    private int id;
    public static int n;

    public ThreadTest(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                if(n >=10000){
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }else{
                    n+=1;
                    System.out.println(" Je suis le thread d'id " + this.id + " n : " + n);
                }
            }           
        }catch(InterruptedException exception){
            System.out.println(" n " + this.n);
        }finally{
            System.out.println(" n " + this.n);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(2));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println("n : " + n);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo siempre obtengo n = 10000, no veo ninguno problema. Por ejemplo la última vez obtenía :

```
 Je suis le thread d'id 2 n : 9999
 Je suis le thread d'id 2 n : 10000
 Je suis le thread d'id 1 n : 9942
 n 10000
 n 10000
```

Comment: Te propongo un cambio en tu código: sustituye `n+=1;System.out.println(" Je suis le thread d'id " + this.id + " n : " + n);` por `System.out.println(" Je suis le thread d'id " + this.id + " n : " + (n+1));
                    n += 1;` y comprueba qué pasa. En principio este cambio no debería afectar al resultado, pero creo que te puede sorprender

Comment: @PabloLozano Si, es más o menos lo mismo. Llego a 10001 en lugar de 10000.

Comment: Por eso hay que sincronizar: hay que evitar que se pueda sumar 1 cuando llegue a 10000... y otro efecto es que no deberías ver a ningún hilo *desfasado*

Answer (score 0):

No sé si he entendido bien tu pregunta pero intento responder.

Tal como lo tienes es difícil trazar algo, cambia las iteraciones a 10, solo por facilitarte el trabajo. Lo que te ocurre en este caso es que de los dos hilos te muestra valores iguales para **n**. ¿Por qué? Porque los dos hilos acceden a la misma variable y la modifican. Como son hilos pueden hacerlo en cualquier momento.

Para sincronizar las ejecuciones es un poco difícil hacerlo sobre una variable estática (no imposible pero sí complejo).

Te propongo el mismo código un poco modificado:

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {
    private int         id;
//  public static int   n;
    private NumHolder num;

    public ThreadTest(int id, NumHolder num) {
        this.id = id;
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (num) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (num.get() >= 10) {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                        System.out.println(" Je suis le thread d'id " + this.id + " SLEEP");
                    } else {
//                      n += 1;
                        num.increment();
                        System.out.println(" Je suis le thread d'id " + this.id + " n : " + num.getAsString());

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION n = " + num.getAsString() + " id - " + this.id);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("FINALLY n = " + num.getAsString() + " id - " + this.id);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumHolder num = new NumHolder();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1, num));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(2, num));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("main n : " + num.getAsString());
    }
}
```

y la clase que falta:

```
public class NumHolder {

    private int n;

    public void increment() {
        n++;
    }

    public int get() {
        return n;
    }

    public String getAsString() {
        return "" + n + " [nano time: " + System.nanoTime() + "]";
    }

}
```

NumHolder lo único que hace es tener la variable **n** mas incrementarla. También hay unos métodos *get*.

La clase principal hace lo mismo que antes. Eso sí, he modificado un poco la ejecución en el main sobre todo con los dos join - es para que el hilo principal espere que se ejecuten los dos hilos ThreadTest. Si no se hace así **System.out.println("main n : " + num.getAsString());** se pinta al principio.

Para ver la sincronización ejecuta la clase tal como está, luego comenta las líneas **synchronized (num) {** y donde cierra la llave (12 líneas más abajo) y vuelve a ejecutar. Veras como la sincronización funciona.

El mismo efecto puedes conseguir si cambias tu variable **n** en ThreadTest por una de tipo AtomicInteger.

No sé si esto te ayuda en algo, si no es así sigue preguntando, intentaremos ayudar.